# phonegap mysql insertion not working after building app

Tags: php, html, mysql, cordova, phonegap

Friends please help, I was new to android phonegap. 
I can't insert to mysql database (in XAMPP server) after building my .apk. 
But insertion is working perfectly on localhost.

Comment: Please ask such questions on Reddit. Stackoverflow is only for specific **code** problems, not a broad, vague questions that are specific to you

Answer (score 0):

In the code, where you login to your DB you need to update your endpoint to your non localhost and also use the new credentials.